# stylelint-selector-bem-pattern BEM linter not working

Tags: gruntjs, postcss, bem, stylelint

In gruntfile

```
stylelint: {
    all: ['app/styles/**/*.scss']
},
```

.stylelintrc

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "stylelint-selector-bem-pattern"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "plugin/selector-bem-pattern": {
      "componentName": "[A-Z]+",
      "componentSelectors": {
        "initial": "^\\.{componentName}(?:-[a-z]+)?$",
        "combined": "^\\.combined-{componentName}-[a-z]+$"
      },
      "utilitySelectors": "^\\.util-[a-z]+$"
    }
    }
}
```

/Users/jitendravyas/app-test/styles/components/_campaign-settings-integrations.scss

```
/* @define campaign-settings */

.campaign-settings__integrations {
  @include flex;
}

.campaign-settings__integration {
  border: 1px solid $color-green;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: $color-green;
  margin-right: $base-spacing-unit;
  @include flex;

  .check {
    background: $color-green;
    color: white;
    @include vertical-center;
  }

  > div {
    padding: $half-spacing-unit;
  }
}
```

**Not getting any error when I run stylelint. Stylelint is working with other rules.**

Answer (score 5):

I believe you have incorrectly defined your component name. As such, the linter is correctly skipping over the file.

You [must use](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-bem-linter#define-componentsutilities-with-a-comment) *either* a *concise* **or** *verbose* syntax:

```
/** @define campaign-settings */
```

or

```
/* postcss-bem-linter: define campaign-settings */
```

At the moment you appear to use an invalid form of the *concise* syntax i.e. your comment begins with `/*`, rather than `/**`.

Comment: In your first comment, do you mean file name and component name should be the same?

Comment: Now I get `Invalid component name in definition /*/** @define campaign-settings */*/   plugin/selector-bem-pattern  ` error